# Citrus SFTP asking for user name and password even after giving user name and password in CITRUS-CONTEXT file

Tags: java, linux, citrus-framework

I am trying to authenticate  to sftp server using citrus I have given usrname and password in context file like this

```
<citrus-sftp:client id="client"
   strict-host-checking="false"
   port="22"
   username="xxxxx"
   password="xxxxxxxx"
   timeout="1000"/>
```

while the program is being executing I am getting some thing prompting like

```
"KEBROS USERNAME :  "
```

after typing username it is asking like

```
"KEBROS PASSWORD :  "
```

then after the program starts executing the commands. what i have to do to eliminate this problem.

Comment: Possibly a typo? usernam**r**e

Comment: I have type wrong but it was username in context.xml

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: It's a programming question why do you think it's not a programming question. The mentioned problem is making my program to wait for inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication prompting for username and password authentication.

By default the Kerberos/GSSAPI `gssapi-with-mic` is one of the first authentication methods chosen by client and server when using JSch client. The solution is to remove `gssapi-with-mic` from the list of preferred authentication methods in JSch session:

```
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,password,keyboard-interactive");
```

Unfortunately you can not set this config with the current Citrus SFTP client implementation (see issue https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus/issues/483).

So you might try to disable `gssapi-with-mic` authentication method on your server in your environment. Or you can try to disable the authentication in your local `$HOME/.ssh/config` config file with

```
Host *
  GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

In general you have wait for Citrus to fix the issue in order to be able to set preferred authentication methods in JSch session on the SFTP client endpoint.